# How to get IParseTree in ANTLR4?

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4, parse-tree

I am currently using ANTLR4 in C# but I am facing a problem, I don't know how to get the the object/class IParseTree.

I find in C#  the fully qualified name here is `Antlr4.Runtime.Tree.IParseTree` but how to get the object?

```
AntlrInputStream inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(sSpinTexte);
SpinParserLexer SpinLexer = new SpinParserLexer(inputStream);
CommonTokenStream commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(SpinLexer);
SpinParserParser SpinParser = new SpinParserParser(commonTokenStream);
IParseTree tree = ?????
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Educated guess from using ANTLR with Java. Did you tried `IParseTree tree = SpinParser.yourStartRuleName();` ? Substitute `yourStartRuleName` with the name of the rule you would like to parse. This is how it works in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of [Cv4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401789/how-to-get-iparsetree-in-antlr4#comment30467637_20401789), this is the code I used:

```
IParseTree tree = SpinParser.expr();
```